# Dataframe loaded with different column type, and how to convert an ArrayType column to another

Tags: pyspark

I have a dataframe with a column I created with collect_set. its type is:

```
t.StructField("list_of_stuff", t.ArrayType(t.StringType(), False), True)
```

I want to create a test which will validate the dataframe by comparing it to another one I'm loading from a json file while using the same schema.
Although all the rows in the file contains valid array values in this field, the loaded data frame gets a schema with the below type (other columns are the same):

```
t.StructField("list_of_stuff", t.ArrayType(t.StringType(), True), True)
```

So, when I try to compare it by using assert_frame_equal, I get an error that the column is not the same.

So 2 questions here:

1. Why does it load with t.ArrayType(t.StringType(), True) if I supplied a schema with t.ArrayType(t.StringType(), False)?
2. How can I convert this column to t.ArrayType(t.StringType(), False)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to handle #2:

```
converter = udf(lambda x: x, t.ArrayType(t.StringType(), False))
df = df.withColumn("list_of_stuff", converter("list_of_stuff"))
```